# Xamarin forms draw signature

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any plugin or default controls to draw signatures in Xamarin forms which will support in all platforms? Do I need to implement in all platforms using dependency service or custom renders?

Answer (score 2):

You can check [this](https://components.xamarin.com/view/signature-pad) component from [Xamarin Components](https://components.xamarin.com/).